# How to extract tuples from a pandas symmetric dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-algebra

I have a dataframe representing a symmetric matrix:

```
  a b c d
a   2 3 4
b 2   6 8
c 3 6   5
d 4 8 5
```

From where I want to go to:

```
[(a,b,2),(a,c,3),(a,d,4),(b,c,6),...]
```

Is there a pythonic/pandatic/ algebraic way of doing it or I should go of for loops?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.unstack().reset_index().values
```

This will keep duplicates in a sense that both `(a, b, 2)` and `(b, a, 2)` will be in the list. You can then filter on `lambda t: t[0] < t[1]`.